# Replace return with a tab for standard input

Tags: c++, g++

I was writing a program in C++ to input values for a NxN matrix. Generally, one would enter an integer and press the Return key for NxN times. But I would like to make the cursor move the length of a tab for every value entered by the user. This carries on for a row, and then a new line is prompted for inputs for the next row. I am aware of using curses.h for such an implementation, but haven't figured out how to implement it.

Thanks.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char ch[10];
  int array[4][4];
  initscr();
  raw();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  echo();

  printw("Enter elements a 4x4 array: \n");
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for(int j=0 ; j<4; j++) {
      getstr(ch);
      array[i][j]=atoi(ch);
      addch('\t'); // This is executed after the newline return is received
      refresh();
    }
    addch('\n');
  }

  getch();
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is lacking code : what have you tried ? What is the problem ?

If you want to get into `ncurses` and don't know where to start, I'd recommend reading some tutorials : see [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/init.html#INITEX) and [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html) regarding keyboard interfacing. Feel free to come and ask more questions if you encounter issues once you have some code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. Now the problem is this: the function getstr will make continuous calls to getch untill a newline return is received. I want to capture the newline return and convert it into a tab ie addch('\t'). In the current code it happens on every new line. How can we intercept the newline return and place a tab on the screen?

Comment: @ajmartin: then you should probably not used `getstr` but a 'naked' `getch` in order to catch the newline yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you input values with `cin >> value;` then any whitespace is a separator. You can also enter a tab or a space instead of return (except then the value is available to be read, not read immediately).

Comment: How is that related to the question? OP wants to hide user input and display it in his own format.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to modify the user input and display something different?

That's not a very good idea (it will be extremely confusing for the user).

If the user decided to press enter after each item, there should be enter after each item. If he just divides the items with a space, it shouldn't display something else.

Comment: To echo your own question: How is this related to the question?

Comment: @Chris I guess I should make it a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: No, I don't want to modify the user input. Basically for every value the user enters, I want to give a tab space instead of a new line. You can look at the code now.